# Is it possible to change angular2-datepicker bigbanner timeformat?

Tags: angular, datepicker, time-format

We are using angular2-datepicker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datetimepicker) in our project. We need to use 24 hour timeformat.
But it looks like it does not work throughout the component.

In the screenshot below, you can see I can change the format in the field marked by 1., but not the format of the fields marked by 2. or 3.

You can see the settings im using here: https://angular-xsv9yq.stackblitz.io

Is this a bug in the component or am i missing a setting?

[image]

Comment: Why don´t guys use https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview ? Or you guys need time and date on the same component?

Comment: We need time and date in same component. We are open to usíng another if we can find a better alternative than the angular2-datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are open to using alternative to angular2-datepicker you could use [OwlDateTimePicker](https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker).

From their Readme:

1) Install with npm:

```
npm install ng-pick-datetime --save
```

2) Add styles. If you are using Angular CLI, you can add this to your styles.css:

```
@import "~ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css";
```

If you are not using the Angular CLI, you can include the picker.min.css via a  element in your index.html.

3) Add OwlDateTimeModule and OwlNativeDateTimeModule to your @NgModule like example below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyTestApp } from './my-test-app';

import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        BrowserModule, 
        OwlDateTimeModule, 
        OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
    ],
    declarations: [ MyTestApp ],
    bootstrap:    [ MyTestApp ]
})
export class MyTestAppModule {}
```

4) Connecting a picker to an input and a trigger.

```
<input [owlDateTime]="dt1" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1" placeholder="Date Time">
<owl-date-time #dt1></owl-date-time>
```

or

```
<input [owlDateTime]="dt2" placeholder="Date Time">
<span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
<owl-date-time #dt2></owl-date-time>
```

Check out [more examples here](https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/).